# Why are currency notes kept in the hand of Varanasi Annapurna?

Tags: temple, kashi

[image]

The Golden Annapurna of Varanasi is seen to hold currency notes in the pot in Her left hand.

Mother Annapurna according to the dhyana-sloka is known to hold a pot of rice. Why are then currency notes kept here?

Comment: Notes instead of rice? Ha Ha

Comment: @Rickross yes.But why? Any idea?

Comment: Sorry no idea.. do you know?

Comment: @Rickross no i dont.One reason couod be that instead of jeeping it empty, its filled with money,Keeping cooked rice is not possible as its considerd 'uchchhista'.